# Updating lateral components on token update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 4 files,

App.js

- Login.js
- Header.js
- Content.js

I'm using a token based login system which is working well. However when I submit the login form and then add the token to local storage I want to update header to go from a login button to "Welcome, [username]". Currently I have to refresh the page for the Header component to be mounted again and therefore for it to display "Welcome, [Username]".

Conversely when a user logs out while on Content.js (the logout button is in Header.js) I want the content to disappear immediately, currently it needs a refresh like above.

My original thought was to pass the token down from App.js along with a callbacks to set and delete it like

```
    <Login
        token={token}
        setToken={setToken}
    />
```

Or something similar, but im using a switch/router and can't find a way to do it.

How should I go about this?

Comment: If you're using an OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token, then a portion of it is a base64 encoded string of whatever you put in it on the server side. Upon successful login, grab the token and before putting it into locastorage, decode the base64 part of it, which will presumably contain the user's name, and display it anywhere you want immediately.

Comment: The problem isn't getting the username, it's the fact that on successful login the header component doesnt remount so the display doesn't change